# Disable autocomplete on regular text input, but allow back>forward saving of value

Tags: html, input, autocomplete

I have an html input field, type text, that is not a password or any type of sensitive information. It is used frequently to put in dollar values. Autocomplete by a browser is annoying because it comes up every time, gets in the way (for some fields this system has its own autocomplete so that's crazy and I disable it there too, though not on this one). The field just requires typing in a dollar value which is different almost every time so autocomplete isn't very useful.

I used the autocomplete="off" on this field.

Then the users mentioned that now when they hit back in their browser, then forward, the value is cleared out. I traced it to this, that's indeed what it does. Other fields keep their values just fine as dictated by the browser's behavior.

Now how to I allow this saving of the value, but disallow the actual autocomplete? This change that came along with autocomplete is unwanted for me. I also don't see it mentioned at all on the w3schools page for autocomplete, but it does it in Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks for any suggestions. The simple thing would be to just allow autocomplete again so I might end up doing that :/

Answer (score 1):

You could keep autocomplete off but create a local storage value that persists that particular fields last value, you could trigger when the value changes. When the page is loaded you would then have a function that checks to see if the value is in local storage and if so populate that field.

Here is an article on using local storage - http://www.thomashardy.me.uk/using-html5-localstorage-on-a-form

Comment: Thank you. Great link, I wasn't aware of this, but it makes a lot of sense that HTML 5 would enable it. That would work I'm sure. I just don't know if I want to do that over just allowing autocomplete again for simplicity and maintenance reasons. Great to know that's an option though.